# Refreshing after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason after I click submit the page goes white and then refreshes and I want to prevent that. I looked through my code and couldn't find what would be causing the page to refresh like that. Im guessing it has to do with an infinite loop and is causing the page to crash but I cant seem to find the bug

this is the url to my code (HTML, CSS, JS, Jquery)

http://codepen.io/epmiles/pen/ewEjn?editors=011

Comment: it's because the form is being submitted. you need to intercept it so that it doesn't submit

Comment: try adding `return false` after your form is submitted to prevent it from refreshing

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens by default in a browser.

Right now you're waiting for the click event on the submit `button`, you shouldn't do that. You're better off waiting for the submit event on the `form` itself.

If you want to stop the submit event from happening you need to prevent the default behavior.

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do your thing...
});
```

There's also a few things you can to keep your code DRY.

Since you do this at the top of your script...

```
var pass = $('#password1');
```

You don't need to do this...

```
$('#password1').addClass('failure');
```

You can just do this..

```
pass.addClass('failure');
```

and

```
pass.val();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Html Correction:
<form.... onSubmit = return validationFunctionName()>

Jquery correction:
  function validationFunctionName(){
  if(soMeCondition)//if this is true validation fails
  return false;
}
```

Comment: So when i add either the return false or $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); it no longer allows the input values to change color (addClass)